# Getimagesize return array instead of boolean

Tags: php

I have image upload form on the site which allow users to upload their images. Now I'm trying to secure it as much as possible. Using php_image_magician..

This is what I have where I check images ( part of code )

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++) {
  if ($_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] <> "") {

    $image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])));

$tempFile =  $_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i];
$getImgSize = getimagesize($tempFile);   

    // if valid image type then upload
    if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check, $getImgSize)) {
        ....
        // upload image
    }
```

Whit `image_type_to_mime_type` there is no problems. Now I have added this lines for `getimagesize` but I got error in here `if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check, $getImgSize))` - `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 3 to be boolean, array given in`. Parameter 3 is `$getImgSize`

```
$tempFile =  $_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i];
$getImgSize = getimagesize($tempFile);
```

`var_dump($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])` return `string(14) "/tmp/phpkBZOW3"`

The form is accepting more than one image so that's why is `for` there and `[$i]`. What can be the problem here?

Comment: I don't think there is "right" order in passing arguments or it has? 1st argument check image mime, 2nd argument check `jpeg/png/bmp/etc` and 3rd check getimagesize..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this. But as @Paul said check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++) {
  if ($_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] <> "") {
    $image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])));

    $getImageFile = getimagesize($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i]);

    if(!empty($getImageFile)){
        echo 'Please ensure you are uploading an image.';
        exit;
    }    

    // if valid image type then upload
    if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check)) {
```

Comment: Thank you. That's work great and I see now where was my mistake.